# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'MessageCategoryID'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html.dropdownlistfor, asp.net-core-7.0

I am getting error: There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'MessageCategoryID'while sending post request to server. The data is not being added to database. I'm using dropdownlistfor.

## Controller

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var client = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient();
            var responseMessage = await client.GetAsync("http://localhost:5173/api/MessageCategory");

            var jsonData = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ResultMessageCategoryDto>>(jsonData);

            List<SelectListItem> values2 = (from x in values
                                            select new SelectListItem
                                            {
                                                Text = x.MessageCategoryName,
                                                Value = x.MessageCategoryID.ToString()
                                            }).ToList();
            ViewBag.v = values2;
            return View();

        }
```

## View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.MessageCategoryID, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.v, new {@class = "form-control"})
```

Comment: You've assigned MessageCategoryID to Value on the SelectListItems that are returned to the view - try `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.Value, ...)` instead.

Comment: CS1061 'CreateContactDto' does not contain a definition for 'value' and no accessible extension method 'value' accepting a first argument of type 'CreateContactDto' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)  it gives me error.

Comment: When you submit post, does the post action return to the same page? If yes, probably you miss out to assign `ViewBag.v` before returning to the View for the same page.

Comment: I was redirecting to other page it was okay. But I couldn't see the error. After I changed redirection to return the view to see error message.

Comment: Would be great if you can share the Post API action implementation.

Comment: can you please check it in my GitHub account? https://github.com/MuradMekhtiev/ProjectHotel

Comment: @MuradMextiev I was not able to find code above in the provided repository

Comment: Can you check it now  please?